# Query with Sum and GroupBy using Criteria

Tags: java, database

I have the following table:

```
Order(idOrder, address, cap, price, quantity, date, idProduct, idUser, idCountry)
```

Now, I want to have a table with the same field of this where the field quantity is the sum of the quantity where idProduct is the same.

For example, if I have the following tuples:

```
1, street1, 123, 4, 6, 2000-12-12, 1, 2, 3
2, street1, 123, 4, 1, 2000-12-12, 2, 2, 2
3, street1, 123, 4, 5, 2000-12-12, 2, 2, 2
4, street1, 123, 4, 1, 2000-12-12, 4, 2, 2
```

I want to have:

```
1, street1, 123, 4, 6, 2000-12-12, 1, 2, 3
2, street1, 123, 4, 6, 2000-12-12, 2, 2, 2
4, street1, 123, 4, 1, 2000-12-12, 4, 2, 2
```

I have to use Criteria

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you "have to" use Criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming hibernate: you need to use projections to apply group by criteria.

Example:

```
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Order.class);
    ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
    projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("quantity"));

    crit.setProjection(projList);
```

See this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/CriteriaGroupByCriteria.htm) and [sum example](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/400.html) for more info.

Comment: But in this way all quantities are summed together? Including those of different products?I don'y want this. I want to be added only the quantity of the same product

Answer (score 0):

Use group by operator for the new table... (If question is specific to DB...)

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE (ID(may be auto generated), Select address, cap, price, sum(quantity), date, idProduct, idUser, idCountry from old_table group by address, cap, price, date, idProduct, idUser, idCountry )
```

Comment: L'equivalente sql di ciò che voglio fare con hibernate sarebbe:

    SELEC idorder, address, cap, price, sum(quantity), date, idProduct, idUser, idCountry
    FROM order GROUP BY idProduct

Cosa che non so fare con Criteria o HQL ;(

Comment: the equivalente sql is: SELEC idorder, address, cap, price, sum(quantity), date, idProduct, idUser, idCountry FROM order GROUP BY idProduct Cosa che non so fare con Criteria o HQL ;(